# My account page on Area 51 includes proposals I am not following

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

When I look at the "stats" tab of my Area 51 profile, it lists a proposal under "Following" that I am *not* following. I did flag this proposal as spam, but that is the only way I interacted with it.

**More information:** I am now following a proposal I flagged as spam (don't ask), and now it appears *twice* in my list of followed proposals.

Comment: This happened to me as well, after I had flagged a proposal as spam.

Comment: Confirmed - I am now also apparently following a proposal I flagged as spam.

Comment: confirmed, see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52960/flagging-proposal-as-spam-put-it-in-my-list-of-followed-sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed.