# Flagging proposal as spam put it in my list of followed sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My account page on Area 51 includes proposals I am not following](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52395/my-account-page-on-area-51-includes-proposals-i-am-not-following)

I flagged an Area 51 site proposal as spam today and now it shows up in my list of followed proposals.

Comment: confirmed, me too

Comment: Possible dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52395/my-account-page-on-area-51-includes-proposals-i-am-not-following

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed.